# How do I log in manually and then use scrapy to scrape sites?

Tags: python, scrapy

I have a list of urls that I have collected, and I want to scrape information from each link, but I need to be logged into the site (steamspy.com) before I can access the information. What I would like to do is just log in manually (using my hands) one time, and then I will be able to scrape the sites. How do I do this? Here is my current code:

```
import scrapy
from scrapy.item import Item, Field
import re


class WorkshopItem(Item):
    developer = Field()
    publisher = Field()
    genre = Field()
    languages = Field()
    tags = Field()
    category = Field()
    release_date = Field()
    old_userscore = Field()
    metascore = Field()
    owners = Field()
    owners_7_day_average = Field()
    players_in_the_last_2_weeks = Field()
    followers = Field()
    peak_concurrent_players_yesterday = Field()
    youTube_stats = Field()
    playtime_in_the_last_2_weeks = Field()
    playtime_total = Field()


class Steamspy_Spider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'steamspy'

    #with open("output/teamfortress2_comment_links.txt") as f:
    #    urls = [line.rstrip("\n") for line in f]
    #start_urls = urls
    start_urls = ['https://steamspy.com/app/440']

    def parse(self, response):
        item = WorkshopItem()
        app_info = response.css(".p-r-30 > p:nth-child(2)").get()
        app_info = re.sub('<.*?>', '', app_info)
        print(app_info)

        item['developer'] = re.search("Developer:.*?Publisher").group(1)
        item['publisher'] = re.search("Publisher:.*?Genre").group(1)
        item['genre'] = re.search("Genre:.*?Languages").group(1)
        item['languages'] = re.search("Languages:.*?Tags").group(1)
        item['tags'] = re.search("Tags:.*?Category").group(1)
        item['category'] = re.search("Category:.*?Release date").group(1)
        item['release_date'] = re.search("Release date:.*?Free").group(1)
        item['old_userscore'] = re.search("Old userscore:.*?Metascore").group(1)
        item['metascore'] = re.search("Metascore:.*?Publisher").group(1)
        item['owners'] = re.search("Developer:.*?Owners").group(1)
        item['owners_7_day_average'] = re.search("Owners :.*?Followers").group(1)
        item['players_in_the_last_2_weeks'] = re.search("Developer:.*?Publisher").group(1)
        item['followers'] = re.search("Followers :.*?Peak concurrent").group(1)
        item['peak_concurrent_players_yesterday'] = re.search("Peak concurrent players yesterday :.*?YouTube stats").group(1)
        item['youTube_stats'] = re.search("YouTube stats :.*?Playtime in the last 2 weeks").group(1)
        item['playtime_in_the_last_2_weeks'] = re.search("Playtime in the last 2 weeks:.*?Playtime total").group(1)
        item['playtime_total'] = re.search("Playtime total:.*?").group(1)

        return item
```

Comment: Why not logging in from script?

Comment: There is a recaptcha

Answer (score 1):

Its possible

Login to the website manually using your computer browser

Then open `Inspect Element`

Then right-click on html request and `Copy as cURL (bash)` command as shown in screenshot

[image]

Then go to https://curl.trillworks.com/ website and paste your copied content

You will have the `cookies` variable there, just copy it and use in your Scrapy code.

Comment: Thank you for your response! Can you elaborate on "use in your Scrapy code"?